# {01/01/0001 00:00:00} being passed as default date and time, MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime

Whenever i try to update an object that has a registered date field, this value is being passed in the model

```
  {01/01/0001 00:00:00}
```

It happens even when i add

```
  <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.RegisteredDate) %>
```

into the view, even though the registered date is displayed in the editor like

```
 18/03/2011 00:00:00
```

The other value is being passed and throwing the following error

```
 SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.
```

Has anyone else experienced anything like this?

Comment: I don't know whats wrong but that datetime value is the default. Maybe you are not binding it properly.

Comment: can you also show the action method written in the controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The date you gave - 18/03/2011 - looks to be in the format day/month/year, which is invalid. The default format for DateTime is month/day/year (MM/dd/yyyy). .Net is trying to parse 18 as a month, which obviously is wrong, hence the error and the default datetime value of 01/01/0001 00:00:00 being used.

Comment: Warrior, thanks, the problem was that i was using the wrong date and time default property.